# How can I take user to a webpage automaticly when a USB memory is inserted?

Tags: http, usb

I want to give away USB sticks (in the form of a pen) as advertising and I would like the user to be sent directly to my homepage when the USB memory is connected. 
Is it possible to do?

It does not matter if the user has to accept the redirect only he / she does not need to type in the URL itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If under windows you can refer to Microsoft doc about the autorun.inf file: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This file should be on the root of your USB stick and contains:

```
[AutoRun]
open=http://www.google.com
```

"Sadly", it seems that Microsoft deactivated the autorun feature since Windows 7 (at least) so you may just end up with no way at all to do it.